# вычисляю факториал натурального числа n, которое пользователь введёт с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Не понимаю в чем ошибка

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Zadachi{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int a;
            long b=1;
            Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите натуральное число");

            if(scn.hasNextInt()){
                a=scn.nextInt();
                for(int i=a;i>0;i--){
                }
                System.out.println("Факториал числа "+a+" равен "+b);
            }
            else System.out.println("Ошибка. Введено не число");
        }
```

Comment: У вас пустой цикл `for` — так и надо?

Comment: Напишите что именно происходит не так (код не компилируется? возникает исключение при исполнении? результат не тот? для какого значения?)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Представленое решение не совсем верное. Если ввести, например, число 123, то результатом будет 0. Если уже пожертвовать временем работы, то можно переписать на `BigInteger` и тогда результат будет правильный.

Вот пример кода:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ONE;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Введите натуральное число");
    if (scn.hasNextInt()) {
        a = scn.nextInt();
        for (int i = a; i > 0; i--) {
            bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Факториал числа " + a + " равен " + bi);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ошибка. Введено не число");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо VladD, нашел ошибку, у меня был пустой for, почему-то пропустил этот момент.
Cкидываю вам правильное решение моей проблемы

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Zadachi{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int a;
            long b=1;
            Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите натуральное число");

            if(scn.hasNextInt()){

                a=scn.nextInt();

                for(int i=a;i>0;i--){
                    b*=i;
                }
                System.out.println("Факториал числа "+a+" равен "+b);
            }
            else System.out.println("Ошибка. Введено не число");
        }
    }
```